# How to wrap multiple Swig modules when using CMake

Tags: python, c++, swig

I am building a library using C++ and Swig, using cmake to generate my build files.The library is a set of classes, where for each class i have,

```
class1.cpp, class1.h, class1.i
class2.cpp, class2.h, class2.i
etc for each classn,
```

In my CMakeLists.txt I have the following lines,

```
SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(classn.i PROPERTIES CPLUSPLUS ON)
SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(classn.i PROPERTIES SWIG_FLAGS "-includeall")
SWIG_ADD_MODULE(Classn python classn.i classn.cpp)
SWIG_LINK_LIBRARIES(Classn ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

for each n class. This works fine and is perfectly functional, however it is a bit of a pain to use in my python scripts. If I want to create an object of class n for instance I would have

```
class_object = Classn.Classn();
```

What I would prefer is

```
class_object = my_library.Classn();
```

How could this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a separate `my_library.i` file and `%include` the classes you want in it. See [File inclusion](http://swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Preprocessor)

```
%module my_library

%include class1.i
%include class2.i
```

and then add something like

```
SWIG_ADD_MODULE(my_library python my_library.i )
SWIG_LINK_LIBRARIES(my_library ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

to the appropriate cmake file

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I did this and it compiled fine, however when i try to import the library I get an Undefined symbol error as though it is not linked correctly.

Comment: Ah, I needed to add a line, `SWIG_LINK_LIBRARIES(my_library class1 class2 ... classn)` which were created with cmakes usual add_library() system.